# Is it possible to have a 32 bit process and a 64 bit process read and write to the same Sqlite database file?

Tags: windows, sqlite

We had two 32 bit Windows applications that both read and wrote to the same database file to exchange information. Up to now we used an MS-Access database for this. This lead to problems when we upgraded one of the two applications to 64 bit, but did not upgrade the other: we got problems with corrupted memory. In the end we solved this by having the 64 bit application talk to a new 32 bit process that did the CRUD operations for it.
Now we envision switching to a Sqlite database. How will this database behave when a 32 bit and a 64 bit process will both perform read an write actions to it? It is likely we will have to use the solution above again?

Answer (score 1):

The sqlite [file format](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html) doesn't depend on the word size the version of the library that created it was compiled with. You can freely use the same database file with 32-bit and 64-bit applications.

Comment: that is a relief, but will the file indeed support concurrent use by a 64 and a 32 bit process? Will Windows support it? As stated above we got nasty errors when we tried to do that with an MS-Access (2000) file.

Comment: It should, though Windows can be strange about files.